# Как извлечь данные поблочно при постоянном изменении значения ключа?

Tags: python, json

Как распарсить JSON? Нужно извлечь поблочно `origin` и `destination` при условии, что значение ключа `data` меняется каждый раз.

```
{"success":true,"data":{"AER":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"AER","price":2116,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":322,"departure_at":"2020-01-27T08:50:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-29T13:45:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T05:41:33Z"},"BAK":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"BAK","price":4024,"transfers":0,"airline":"J2","flight_number":9718,"departure_at":"2020-05-20T17:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-05-31T16:00:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T10:18:25Z"},"DXB":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"DXB","price":16630,"transfers":1,"airline":"UT","flight_number":574,"departure_at":"2020-02-08T06:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-12T16:00:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T06:06:46Z"},"EVN":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"EVN","price":8070,"transfers":1,"airline":"A4","flight_number":258,"departure_at":"2020-02-12T19:20:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-18T17:05:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T23:17:09Z"},"HAN":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"HAN","price":35610,"transfers":2,"airline":"UT","flight_number":374,"departure_at":"2020-01-22T14:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-29T08:55:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T04:18:36Z"},"IST":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"IST","price":8032,"transfers":1,"airline":"J2","flight_number":9718,"departure_at":"2020-10-08T17:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-10-11T00:40:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T11:44:50Z"},"LED":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"LED","price":5357,"transfers":0,"airline":"DP","flight_number":540,"departure_at":"2020-01-22T12:10:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-05T08:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T21:01:14Z"},"MOW":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"MOW","price":3385,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":574,"departure_at":"2019-12-22T06:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-13T17:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T06:00:00Z"},"TJM":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"TJM","price":7600,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":510,"departure_at":"2020-01-02T11:10:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-09T08:55:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T10:20:49Z"},"TLV":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"TLV","price":15520,"transfers":2,"airline":"UT","flight_number":274,"departure_at":"2020-02-05T20:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-09T05:40:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T17:24:06Z"}},"error":null,"currency":"rub"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/):

```
import json
import dpath.util as dp   #  pip install dpath

data = json.loads(jstr)
origins = dp.values(data, "/data/**/origin")
destinations = dp.values(data, "/data/**/destination")
```

---

результат:

```
In [11]: origins
Out[11]: ['MRV', 'MRV', 'MRV', 'MRV', 'MRV', 'MRV', 'MRV', 'MRV', 'MRV', 'MRV']

In [12]: destinations
Out[12]: ['AER', 'BAK', 'DXB', 'EVN', 'HAN', 'IST', 'LED', 'MOW', 'TJM', 'TLV']
```